# Docker: Como referencio um serviço definido em um container em outro?

Tags: docker

Tenho alguns sites em um VPS rodando com o docker-compose, numa mesma network e usando proxy. A estrutura é mais ou menos esta:

```
.
├── nginx-proxy
│   └── docker-compose.yml
└── blogs
    └── docker-compose.yml
```

Dentro da pasta blogs eu tenho esta configuração:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_DB_NAME}
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${DB_PATH}:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

  wordpress1:
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_WP_NAME1}
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${WP_CORE}:/var/www/html
      - ${WP_CONTENT}:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./conf.d/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${CONTAINER_DB_NAME1}:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE1}
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER1}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD1}
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX1}
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${DOMAINS1}
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${DOMAINS1}
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL1}
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: ${LOGGING_OPTIONS_MAX_SIZE1:-200k}

  wordpress2:
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_WP_NAME2}
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${WP_CORE}:/var/www/html
      - ${WP_CONTENT}:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./conf.d/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${CONTAINER_DB_NAME2}:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE2}
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER2}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD2}
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX2}
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${DOMAINS2}
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${DOMAINS2}
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL2}
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: ${LOGGING_OPTIONS_MAX_SIZE2:-200k}

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ${NETWORK}
```

Tudo está funcionando bem, mas eu quero refatorar isto para que se torne mais fácil de manter com o tempo. A idéia seria retirar a declaração do serviço mysql do arquivo acima, bem como as declarações dos blogs. Então eu criaria um diretório com a configuração para o serviço de DB, outro para o blog1 e outro para o blog2. Exemplo:

```
.
├── db
│   └── docker-compose.yml
├── blog1
│   └── docker-compose.yml
├── blog2
│   └── docker-compose.yml
└── blog3
    └── docker-compose.yml
```

#### db container

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_DB_NAME}
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${DB_PATH}:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ${NETWORK}
```

#### blog1 container

```
version: "3"

services:
  wordpress1:
    depends_on:
      - db // Isto funciona? O Docker saberá
           // que este é o serviço mysql que
           // consta no outro diretório?

    container_name: ${CONTAINER_WP_NAME1}
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
        - ${WP_CORE}:/var/www/html
        - ${WP_CONTENT}:/var/www/html/wp-content
        - ./conf.d/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${CONTAINER_DB_NAME1}:3306
        WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE1}
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER1}
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD1}
        WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX1}
        VIRTUAL_HOST: ${DOMAINS1}
        LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${DOMAINS1}
        LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL1}
    logging:
        options:
        max-size: ${LOGGING_OPTIONS_MAX_SIZE1:-200k}
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ${NETWORK}
```

... e outra para o blog2, blog3 e por aí vai.

Agora vem a dúvida: como referencio um serviço externo ao arquivo de configuração atual? Em outras palavras, como faço para incluir o db como dependência em cada arquivo de configuração dos blogs?

Qualquer ajuda seria muito bem vinda. Obrigado!